# Laravel 3 way relation

Tags: laravel, relationship

```
user
id *
name

reviewers
type_id *
user_id *
user_id

reviewer_types
id *
name
```

How would I create the reviewers relation in Laravel?
Result should be:

```
reviewers
type_id: 1 
user_id: 1
user_id: 2
```

Comment: It's not clear what are `1, 1, 2` (IDs of users? IDs of reviewers?). Also, please show what relations you're currently using.

Comment: I wrote the Schema at the top. It shows that the reviewers table has a type_id and 2 user_ids.

Comment: take a look at polymorphic relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Can you make it more clear? I mean what is the purpose in your project that you want to achieve with the design you mentioned? More clarification will make it easier to get proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Reviewer
{
    public function user1()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id_1');
    }

    public function user2()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id_2');
    }

    public function reviewType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ReviewType::class, 'type_id');
    }
}

Reviewer::with('user1')->with('user2')->with('reviewType')->first();
```

Hope this helps